# Grounding a sub panel panel properly

Tags: electrical

I have 3 panels
1) Main Breaker
2) Sub Panel
3) Sub Panel serviced/fed from (2)

Can I ground Panel (3) to Panel (1)?

The reason why I want to is I can use one size smaller conduit between (2) and (3) [1 and 3 are located beside each-other], which for this installation would be a **HUGE** advantage!!

Comment: If panel 1 and panel 3 are next to each other, then why is the feeder for panel 3 run from panel 2 to begin with, not panel 1? It sounds like you're spending a bunch of money you don't need to spend...

Answer (score 1):

> Can I ground Panel (3) to Panel (1)?

Assuming all panels are in the same building.

The answer is yes, but only if you feed Panel (3) from Panel (1)(see comment from @. ThreePhaseEel). The NEC requires all conductors to run together as a group.